# Qualtrics: Import AdvancedFormat with Validation Rules

Tags: validation, import, qualtrics

I am trying to load a survey from a TXT file using the AdvancedFormat.  My survey looks great but I need to add some validation options for the questions. I have not found any documentation that discusses this option.

Can anyone provide an example how to include validation or confirm that it is not possible to import validations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include validations when you import a TXT file.  You'll have to add them in Qualtrics after you import. There are lots of things not supported with AdvancedFormat TXT import.  The only way to do a full function import is with a QSF file, but that would be very laborious to create manually.